# Converting Excel-Sheet to markdown table with breaks between multiple lines in a cell

Tags: python, pandas, markdown, xlsx

I am writing a python script that should take a excel spreadsheet and convert it to a markdown table. Currently my code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('TestMap1.xlsx')
md_table = df.to_markdown(index=False)
print(md_table)
```

Basically this works, but I have the problem, that if there are multiple lines in a excel cell, the .to_markdown() method puts them into seperate cells in the markdown syntax.

Example:

This is the excel table

[image]

and the .to_markdown() method converts it into this:

[image]

As you can see, the "Some Info" column of the "Couch" object should have 3 seperate lines in them, but the markdown table has every line in a seperate cell.

I want it to look like this:

[image]

That means, that instead of generating a new table row for each line in that cell, the .to_markdown() method has to put `<br>` tags between the lines.

The script should work with excel spreadsheets of various sizes.

Is there a way to do that with pandas? If no, is there a different library that supports such operations?

---

Data as dict: {'Object': {0: 'Lamp', 1: 'Couch', 2: 'Shoes'}, 'Price': {0: 20, 1: 200, 2: 50}, 'Some Info': {0: 'Pretty Bright', 1: '2 meters long\nblue\ncomfy', 2: 'Size 9.5'}}

Comment: can you share data as dict please

Comment: i have added the data as dictionary to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace all new line characters by `'br'` tag.

Applying `string method` to all non numeric values.

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('\n', '<br>') if x.dtype == 'object' else x)
```

which gives us :

```
  Object  Price                           Some Info
0   Lamp     20                       Pretty Bright
1  Couch    200  2 meters <br>long<br>blue<br>comfy
2  Shoes     50                            Size 9.5
```

##### Output :

```
print(df.to_markdown())
```

For the data you shared.

This gives us the expected output :

|  | Object | Price | Some Info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Lamp | 20 | Pretty Bright |
| 1 | Couch | 200 | 2 meters long blue comfy |
| 2 | Shoes | 50 | Size 9.5 |